# Run Querys on List of Databases (For Each loop?)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a selection of about 15 databases on an SQL server that I want to run some query's on. I do not want to affect any of the roughly 10 other databases.

Specifically, I want to run the following commands:

```
USE MASTER;
GO


ALTER DATABASE DATABASENAME
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO


ALTER DATABASE DATABASENAME
SET OFFLINE
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO


EXEC MASTER.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'DATABASENAME'
GO
```

My goal is to take these databases offline, detach them, move the .mdf and .ldf files to a different disk, then re-attach them using the GUI.

In an ideal world, I would also love to be able to then run the following command on them after all have been re-attached:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename SET ENABLE_BROKER
```

In a perfect world, I would be able to designate a list of databases and then loop through all of the commands.

Something PowerShell-y would look like this:

```
$Databasesnames = @("Database1","Database2","Database3")
ForEach ($Databasename in $Databasenames)
{
USE MASTER;
GO


-- Take database in single user mode
ALTER DATABASE $Databasename
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO


--Take databace offline
ALTER DATABASE $Databasename
SET OFFLINE
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO


-- Detach DB
EXEC MASTER.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'$Databasename'
GO
}
```

And then after something like

```
$Databasesnames = @("Database1","Database2","Database3")
ForEach ($Databasename in $Databasenames)
{
ALTER DATABASE $Databasename SET ENABLE_BROKER
}
```

I tried this T-SQL ‘while loop approxmiation’ without any luck:

```
--Set Base Table for Loop Action, Add Database Names
USE TEMPDB
GO
CREATE TABLE #DBS
(Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(100), Status TINYINT)
GO
INSERT INTO #DBS ( Id, Name, Status)
Values (1, 'Database1', 0),
        (2, 'Database2', 0),
        (3, 'Database3', 0)
GO


--Loop through DB names, taking them offline and detaching them. 
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @MaxDBId INT = 3 , 
        @DBName NVARCHAR(100)


WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MaxDBId)
BEGIN
   SELECT @DBName = Name
   FROM #DBS WHERE Id = @LoopCounter
USE MASTER
GO
-- Take database in single user mode
ALTER DATABASE @DBName
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO


--Take DB Offline
ALTER DATABASE @DBName SET OFFLINE WITH
ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO


-- Detach DB
EXEC MASTER.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname
GO


   SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1        
END
```

**UPDATE 1**
Here is my revised script

```
--Declare base Dynamic SQL Variables

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

DECLARE @sql2 nvarchar(max);


--Set Base Table for Loop Action, Add Database Names
USE TEMPDB
GO
CREATE TABLE #DBS
(Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(100), Status TINYINT)
GO
INSERT INTO #DBS ( Id, Name, Status)
Values (1, 'Database1', 0),
        (2, 'Database2', 0),
        (3, 'Database3', 0)
GO


--Loop through DB names, taking them offline and detaching them. 
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @MaxDBId INT = 3 , 
        @DBName NVARCHAR(100)

WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MaxDBId)
BEGIN
   SELECT @DBName = Name
   FROM #DBS WHERE Id = @LoopCounter
USE MASTER
GO

 SET @sql = N'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) 
    + N' SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;';

 SET @sql2 = N'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) 
    + N' SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql2;

EXEC MASTER.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname;
GO


SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1


END
```

Comment: What were the results from the code you tried?  Edit your answer to include error messages, etc.

Comment: I never got it working quite right, but Dynamic SQL was definitely the answer to my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ALTER DATABASE` does not take arguments for database name, so you'll have to construct dynamic SQL, e.g. instead of:

```
ALTER DATABASE @DBName
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

You'll need this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

  ... inside loop ...

  SET @sql = N'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) 
    + N' SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    '
    + N'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) 
    + N' SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;';

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

However assuming you have a backup (and if you don't, you should), why bother detaching? Much cleaner to just drop, then you aren't tempted to use an mdf file as a backup, and you don't have to worry about your data folder being permanently full of abandoned data files...

Comment: Thank you! Do I construct a different dynamic SQL for each ALTER DATABASE query? I updated the code in my question to demonstrate better.

I'm doing it this way to be fast and not tedious. I can detach all dbs, move them, then re-attach them simultaneously within 1 GUI Window (Attatch).

Comment: But it's so much safer to backup, move, and restore than to detach, move, and attach. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups

Comment: is it possible to loop through each server and automate the process for this method from your link?

`USE [master];
GO
 
BACKUP DATABASE dbname TO DISK = N'E:\wherever\dbname.bak' WITH INIT, COPY_ONLY;
 
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
 
RESTORE DATABASE dbname FROM DISK = N'E:\wherever\dbname.bak'
  WITH REPLACE, MOVE N'dbname_log' TO N'F:\new_path\dbname_log.ldf';`

Comment: @AlexanderTheGreat Well, you already have a loop that works, why not just populate that #temp table slightly differently: `CREATE TABLE #DBS
(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name NVARCHAR(100), Status TINYINT)
GO
INSERT INTO #DBS ( Name, Status) SELECT name, 0 FROM sys.databases WHERE <whatever identifies your 15 databases>;` I feel like you're really going way beyond what your original question was trying to solve, though.

Comment: At this point I am definitely just spending 8 hours coding to avoid 2 hours of manual work. I will likely probably just run thorough the recommended backup/restore steps on your site manually for each database. It just sucks, as there are probably closer to 25 databases instead of the 15 originally thought.

Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: There is certainly a way to automate this, I'm just saying this is way beyond the scope of your original question.